# How to embed javascript component in Angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

In my Angular 2 application, I would like to embed this "tags input component" which is written in plain Javacsript:

https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

What would be the correct way to include/embed it in my typescript?

Here is a snippet of my files, where I'd like for the component to appear:

[image]

I'm at a beginner's level with Angular 2 and Typescript, but I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these in your index.html file

```
<script src="jQuery.tagify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tagify.css">
```

add following in your component where you want to use tagify

```
declare var Tagify:any;
```

for example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var Tagify:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

then add tagify logic in `ngAfterViewInit` at your component for example

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[name=tags]'),
    tagify = new Tagify( input );
  }

}
```